# SEHException on isOnAppTrial

Tags: c#, windows-8, unity-game-engine

I have built a new game using Unity's 2D feature set, and I built for Windows 8 and submitted it to Store for certification. I got an error that showed up in the certification process that I am unable to work out how to fix and I am unable to reproduce.

The error that I get is as follows:

```
Exception: External component has thrown an exception.
Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Module: UnityEngineProxy
InnerException: <No Data>
AdditionalInfo: <No Data>
    at UnityEngineProxy.InternalCalls.PInvokeCalls.LicenseInformation_Get_Custom_PropIsOnAppTrial()
    at LevelButtonScript.Update()
    at LevelButtonScript.UnityFastInvoke_Update()
```

And the level button script uses it as follows:

```
            if (UnityEngine.Windows.LicenseInformation.isOnAppTrial && LevelToLoadId > 10)
            {
                Application.LoadLevel("TrialNoteScene");
                return;
            }
```

Essentially I am checking if the app is on trial to stop the player going to levels above level 10. Is there a way around this? (I am building this for Windows Store and Windows Phone Store). This is the only reference to `UnityEngine.Windows.LicenseInformation` in the entire project.

The API reference for Unity doesn't give much information, but it does say the API is only available on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 builds (which are the only 2 places this project is being deployed currently).

Comment: This looks like a bug in Unity.  I think you'll have to submit this to unity support.

Comment: Alrighty, will do. Thanks